# I encrypted the data in java using AES and trying the same to decrypt form javascript, but i am getting empty string as output in . Any suggestions

Tags: javascript, java, encryption, aes, cryptojs

Below Code used for encryption in java side and encrypted data is shared to ui where we need to decrypt. Front end and backend using same key and iv .

```
    public static Optional<String> encrypt(String strToEncrypt) {
            try {
                Field field = Class.forName("javax.crypto.JceSecurity").getDeclaredField("isRestricted");
                field.setAccessible(true);
                Field modifiersField = Field.class.getDeclaredField("modifiers");
                modifiersField.setAccessible(true);
                modifiersField.setInt(field, field.getModifiers() & ~Modifier.FINAL);
                field.set(null, false);
    
                byte[] keyHex = Hex.decodeHex(secretKey.toCharArray());
                byte[] decodeHex = Hex.decodeHex(ivKey.toCharArray());
                IvParameterSpec ivspec = new IvParameterSpec(decodeHex);
    
                SecretKeySpec secretKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(keyHex, AES_ENC);
    
                Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(ALGORITHM);
                cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKeySpec, ivspec);
                String encodedToString = Base64.getEncoder()
                        .encodeToString(cipher.doFinal(strToEncrypt.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)));
                System.out.println("ENC:>"+Base64.getDecoder().decode(encodedToString));
                return Optional.ofNullable(encodedToString);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                //log.error("AesUtil : Error occurred while encrypting the data : " + e);
            }
            return Optional.empty();
        }
    
        public static Optional<String> decrypt(String strToDecrypt) {
    
            try {
                Field field = Class.forName("javax.crypto.JceSecurity").getDeclaredField("isRestricted");
                field.setAccessible(true);
                Field modifiersField = Field.class.getDeclaredField("modifiers");
                modifiersField.setAccessible(true);
                modifiersField.setInt(field, field.getModifiers() & ~Modifier.FINAL);
                field.set(null, false);
    
                byte[] keyHex = Hex.decodeHex(secretKey.toCharArray());
                byte[] decodeHex = Hex.decodeHex(ivKey.toCharArray());
                IvParameterSpec ivspec = new IvParameterSpec(decodeHex);
    
                SecretKeySpec secretKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(keyHex, AES_ENC);
    
                Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(ALGORITHM);
                cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKeySpec, ivspec);
                byte[] decode = Base64.getDecoder().decode(strToDecrypt);
                String finalRes = new String(cipher.doFinal(decode));
                System.out.println(finalRes);
                return Optional.ofNullable(finalRes);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                //log.error("AesUtil : Error occurred while decrypting the data : " + e);
            }
            return Optional.empty();
        }
```

`Below code i tried to decrypt but its printing empty in console log also tried to decode the data  in js and tried to decrypt, but still getting same empty output.

```
const decrypt = ()=>{

    var decode  = atob(encrypted);
var decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt({
    ciphertext: encrypted //decode
 },key, {
    iv: iv,
    mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC,
    padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7
});
    console.log(decrypted.toString()); 
    console.log(decrypted.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8));
    
}
```

Comment: Key, IV (hex encoded) and ciphertext (Base64 encoded) must be decoded with the appropriate [encoders](https://cryptojs.gitbook.io/docs/#encoders) in WordArrays and passed that way. The ciphertext can also be passed Base64 encoded (then *directly*, without `{ciphertext: ...}`).

Comment: @Topaco Thanks a lot for the document  its worked https://cryptojs.gitbook.io/docs/#encoders

Answer (score 0):

```
var decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt({
    ciphertext: CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse(encrypted) //decode
 },CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(key), {
    iv: CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(iv),
    mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC,
    padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7
});
```